# A Harry Potter sequence puzzle

Tags: number-sequence, sequence, literature

What is the next term in the following sequence based on Harry Potter?

> None, 16, None, 16, 5, 9, ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The next term in the sequence is:

> **22**

Because:

> These are the **[chapter numbers](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_chapters_in_the_Harry_Potter_novels)** which share their name with the part of the book title that follows '*Harry Potter and...*' (in order of the books' publication):
>
>  Book 1 - **none**: *no chapter called 'The Philosopher's Stone'*;
>  Book 2 - Chapter **16**: 'The Chamber of Secrets';
>  Book 3 - **none**: *no chapter called 'The Prisoner of Azkaban'*;
>  Book 4 - Chapter **16**: 'The Goblet of Fire';
>  Book 5 - Chapter **5**: 'The Order of the Phoenix';
>  Book 6 - Chapter **9**: 'The Half-Blood Prince';
>  **Book 7 - Chapter 22: 'The Deathly Hallows'.**

**EDIT:** Since some commenters wish to understand the thought process behind my solving this puzzle, here's roughly how I approached it:

> 1) There are 7 terms in the sequence, and there are 7 HP books - let's assume that each term in the sequence maps to one of the books...
>
>  2) Why are the two null entries written as 'None' rather than '0'? This probably means we're not counting something, otherwise the OP would have just used a zero character;
>
>  3) What other numbers are relevant to books - chapter numbers, to start...
>
>  4) Look up the chapters of these numbers in the relevant books;
>
>  5) *GASP AS YOU SPOT THE CONNECTION!!*

Comment: Is this something that you knew already, or did you pour over the books to figure this out?

Comment: @MalachiHolden there are a few hints that would point you in certain directions. First hint is that there are 6 given answers, and they're asking you for the 7 one. If you're familiar with Harry Potter, you know there are 7 books, so there's a good chance the puzzle is a `1 answer per book` type of puzzle.

Comment: @MalachiHolden if it is a `1 answer per book` type of puzzle, the most obvious answers will relate to pages or to chapters. So, you flip to page 16 in book 2, and you flip to page 16 in book 4, and you flip to page 5 in book 5, but you don't immediately see anything.

Comment: @MalachiHolden then you do the same with chapters, and the answer jumps out at you.

Comment: @MalachiHolden My rough thought process was: 1) There are 7 terms in the sequence, and there are 7 HP books - let's assume that each term in the sequence maps to one of the books... 2) Why are the two null entries written as 'None' rather than '0'? This probably means we're not counting something, otherwise the OP would have just used a zero character; 3) What other numbers are relevant to books - *chapter numbers*... 4) Look up the chapters of these numbers in the relevant books; 5) GASP AS YOU SPOT THE CONNECTION!!

Comment: @Stiv: You should edit that into your answer! I am firmly of the belief that good answers on this site explain not just the answer but how you got there too! Its a shame to leave such valuable information in comments!

Comment: @Chris Agreed, and answer updated accordingly :)